# Libre office writer pasting images

Tags: images, libreoffice-writer, paste

Once I have copied and pasted an image to my document, how do I make it fit to the page proportionately? Do i have to do it manually? Or is there a button or easier way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Image, choose `Format Image`. On `Type` tab in Width group choose `relative to` to `Entire page` and select percentage that will image cover the page. For example 100% means that image width is the same as page width.